# Change cursor type for an html document from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, mouse-cursor

Let's say I have a javascript method that takes a little to long to finish to go without any user feedback at all.  In my case it's sorting the rows in a table element (all in the DOM; only takes too long if there are a *lot* of rows), but it might do anything.  I want to show the "progress" cursor while it runs.  Here is what I have currently, but I've tried several other things as well:

```
// SORT   
document.body.style.cursor = "progress";
MyLongRunningMethod(); //blocks for 10-15 seconds before returning
document.body.style.cursor = "auto";
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens.  MyLongRunningMethod() does it's thing correctly, but the cursor never changes.  My thought is that the browser needs to wait for the method to return to be able to handle the cursor change message generated by the windowing environment, but that may be way off and even if it's true I don't know how to fix it.

Any other ideas?

---

[edit]: I decided all the back-story I had up wasn't really necessary.  If you really want to read it check the revision history.

---

**Final Results**

I ended up using RoBorg's solution.  It doesn't mess up the code as much as I was originally thinking, because I can keep the function declared right there- it's just like adding an inline scope block.

Interestingly, on Firefox I discovered that this means I don't need to change the cursor at all.  I found that after I added the setTimeout call I was sometimes seeing a wait cursor show up before the progress cursor was set, so I commented out my cursor code.  It turns out that something in using setTimeout to push this out of the click event handler itself allows FireFox to figure out on it's own that the cursor should change.  Unfortunately, IE is not that smart so I did put the cursor code back.

This lends credence to my belief that a cursor change is the appropriate action here — given the opportunity it's what the browser will do anyway.  I really don't want to have to add and remove new items (like a busy image of some type) into the DOM for a page that I know very little about.  The script should match no matter what visual design the page uses.

Finally, Chrome makes the whole thing irrelevant.  Using the same data, Chrome does in less than 5 seconds what took IE and Firefox 10 to 15 seconds to accomplish.  So their javascript engine really is faster.  I can't wait for the Firefox 3.1 engine.  Unfortunately people here are still mostly using IE6.

Comment: Does SortTable call the server asynchronously?

Comment: No, it does it all on the client with the DOM.

Comment: In other words: it blocks until completion.  I can see this in firebug.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is using a timer out of the question?

```
document.body.style.cursor = "progress";

setTimeout(function()
{
    SortTable(cell.cellIndex, dir, sortType);
    document.body.style.cursor = "auto";
}, 10);
```

Comment: It's less than ideal, certainly, but I may have no other choice :(

Comment: I ended going this route, and here's what I found.  I don't need to set the cursor.  By adding the setTimeout() in there somehow the browser figures out it needs to update the cursor on it's own-- it's able to detect the function is using a lot of cpu.

Comment: Nevermind: that was firefox only.  IE isn't that smart and Chrome finishes fast enough it doesn't need it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In web, changing mouse cursor is not conventional and not nice.

It’s much better (and easier) to use some small animations on the page itself, check http://www.ajaxload.info/ for such images (it’s an online generator).

Comment: Nice link: you'll get an upvote for it later but I'm holding back at the moment so the question stays on the unanswered view a little longer.

Comment: I agree that changing the cursor is bad for an ajax request.  However, this is all in the DOM and can potentially use up a lot of cpu time.  Changing the cursor is the traditional way to indicate that with any application.  Also: progress cursor != wait cursor.

Comment: It depends. Changing it to a pointer is nice and conventional.

Comment: Joel, what is conventional for client apps is not for web apps. I don’t think it’s a good idea to mix those things up. User just does not expect a page to behave like this. But still, technically, your question is not answered by me answer, the other guys deserve more upvotes :-)

Comment: gs, Changing to a pointer is something that browser does, not your script. And in very rare cases you script that, you do it just to emulate the browser behaviour in case you broke it by doing something else. So I guess my point holds true ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the document.body.style.cursor = "auto" and placing it into a function called at completion of your SortTable function. That way you will retain the busy cursor until the function has completed. Be sure that if you reach an error condition within SortTable() that you still hit the "No longer busy" function call.

Comment: I think you mis-read what's going on.  The SortTable function blocks.

Comment: Yep. Definitely missed that. I see it now. And even though it looks like the answer is "Don't do this", I really wonder what's happening here. It looks like the page doesn't bother to display any changes to the style while the script is pending (I tried changing to a blue background).